# Sending a string Value to the WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, asmx, webmethod

```
function EmpCode(empCode) {
    var queryString = "";
    var hasQuerystring = document.URL.indexOf('?');
    if (hasQuerystring != -1) {
        queryString = document.URL.substring(hasQuerystring + 1, document.URL.length);
        if (queryString == 'id=1') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "EmployeeBasicInfo.aspx/CheckEmpCode",
                data: "{'empCode':" + empCode + "}",// Sending empCode which is a string
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var errorMsg = (msg.d);
                    if (errorMsg != 'NA') {
                        alert(errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static  string CheckEmpCode(string empCode)
    {
    string empCod = "";
    EmployeeFactory empFactory = new EmployeeFactory();
    empCod = empFactory.CheckCode(empCode);
    return empCod;
}
```

When i send the empCode as '11479' 0r any integers from Ajax the web method is calling. when i send the empcode as "C1026" or any string with characters then the webmethod is not getting called..

Please suggest me how to pass empCode which is having string value.

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put quotes around the EmpCode.Currently you are sending:

```
data: {'empCode': C1026}
```

You need to send:

```
data: {'empCode': 'C1026'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert.was very Helpful for me